# Python lists error : localvars

Tags: python, django

i am working on this code:

```
poll_list = poll.object.all()
result = []
    for q in poll_list:
        result = result.append(q)
return HttpResponse(result)
```

it gives error of locAL VARS...any body knows the problem in this??

Comment: *"it gives error of locAL VARS"* No, "it" doesn't.

Comment: No, not a typing error. Python does not output an error which simply reads that.

Comment: by typing error i meant that i mistakenly typed locAL VARS...actually it is local vars..i mean you should straigh away have understood this.

Comment: And I mean that you are still lying about the error. Python does not emit "local vars" as the totality of an error. In fact, I doubt it has that as a possible substring of an error at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result = result.append(q)` is definitely not what you want as the call to `append` returns `None` and you assign it to `result` and after that you can't access your list any longer via `result`. It has to be `result.append(q)` which appends `q` into the mutable list.

Comment: Good catch.  You should mention that `result.append` returns `None`.

Answer (score 2):

```
poll_list = poll.object.all()
result = []
for q in poll_list:
    result = result.append(q)
```

Your ident is off by one tab :)

Comment: While you're at it, you can show OP how to condense this down using a list-comprehension :).

Comment: and explaining to them why the end result will be `None`

Comment: identation is very much correct in the code i guess here it got wrong due to copy/paste. the error still persists

Answer (score 1):

```
poll_list = poll.objects.all()
result = [x for x in poll_list]
```

Comment: Wouldn't `result = list(poll_list)` be easier?

Comment: oja, many ways lead to rome :)

Comment: @halex -- or, if the name of `poll_list` is correct, `result = poll_list[:]` :)

Comment: @mgilson But this only works if `poll_list` is NO generator or iterator, doesn't it :) (I don't know what `poll.object.all()` returns)

Comment: @halex -- I know.  That's why I prefaced my comment with "if the name of `poll_list` is correct".  (Otherwise it should be called `poll_iterator` or something ;).  You're right that `list` is the most generic way to go here.